# Is there an IMAP command to search AND sort in one go?

Tags: sorting, email, search, imap

I'm working on a webmail client, and I need to search for email messages based on a keyword and sort the results by date in a single IMAP command. I know that IMAP provides `SEARCH` for searching and sorting is typically done on the client side. However, I wonder if there's a way to combine both actions, i.e. searching and sorting in a single IMAP command for more efficient processing. Is this possible with IMAP, or is there a workaround to achieve this?

The webmail client is in PHP and JavaScript.

The goal is to streamline the process of retrieving and presenting relevant email messages to the user based on their search criteria and sorting preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sort and uid sort](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5256) commands do exactly what you want. Here's a command to search for messages from me, sort them by size and return their UIDs:

```
a uid sort (size) utf-8 from "arnt@gulbrandsen.priv.no"
```

The charset argument is mandatory (unlike SEARCH) and indicates the character encoding of the the searching criteria string. By default, you may use us-ascii instead of utf-8 as well.

Comment: A side comment. If you see a tutorial that tells you to use the keyword `all` as argument to `search` or `sort`, you may assume that you know as much about IMAP as the author of the tutorial does.

Comment: Note: SORT is an IMAP extension you will need to check the CAPABILITY for, and may not exist on some servers.

Comment: @arnt: The charset argument seems to be mandatory: without it server response is `BAD`. Thanks so far for the tip.